# How to use mod rewrite with php?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm just wondering. In some websites I see the following:
http://www.website.com/the-title-of-my-new-book-2011.html

I know how to use a mod rewrite, but I wonder how they get the title separated by the "-" sign. And I don't see any ID, meaning they are using the title of the book to get the ID and show the information from the database. How do they get rid of the "-" sign? And more importantly: How do they link to each article on their website? Which functions are used to achieve all this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of the implementations that I am familiar with are built in the Front Controller design pattern and utilize one script to handle these kinds of specific requests, so that urls routed to locations that do not have a specific controller get handled by the script.  You may want to start looking into design patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things are called [slugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29). When entering a new product, a slug is probably created semi-automaticlly based on the name of the product, for example by removing all non-latin characters, making it lower case and replacing spaces with dashes. This is saved together with the product. When visiting the above URL, the `.html` is stripped and the rest is taken as the slug and used for looking up the product in the database.

Answer (score 1):

They probably catch the full path ( `/the-title-of-my-new-book-2011.html`) using mod_rewrite, cut off `.html` and `2011`, and do a lookup of the rest against a column in their books database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I'm still confused on how they get the title separated by the "-" sign in the first place. Or is mod_rewrite responsible for this?

Comment: @moonwalker I don't understand. What's so special about the `-`? They can't use spaces so they're filling the gaps with dashes. At which point that happens, doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: That I'm aware of, but I thought that mod_rewrite was responsible for putting dashes. The answer of Deceze put me on the right tracks, because I was looking for the word "slugs" all the time. Now I understand how it's done. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @moonwalker Quite the contrary, mod_rewrite takes URLs and tries to make sense of them, it doesn't generate URLs.